# Linux on Xilinx zcu102 crashes "nwl-pcie fd0e0000.pcie: Non-Fatal Error Detected" error

Tags: petalinux

I made a petalinux project with Xilinx 2018.3 sdk environment. I built my project upon a zcu102 Xilinx board, and a PCIe card attached to that board.

I debug my code for some time without error, until it crashes.
it happens after I run external simulator that send data to the pci card. see the photo.
I get endless massages:

> [ 1845.777165] nwl-pcie fd0e0000.pcie: Non-Fatal Error Detected

The error is running on my console continuously and by that time sdk [eclipse] is also stuck and I need to power cycle the board. What does this error mean?

I will provide more details if necessary.
Can you suggest a way to debug this error and get to the root cause?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was not a problem with petalinux version, or cpp code malfunction

the problem arises from the fact that there were 2 fpga modules on pcie card which probably get confused and cause the os to crash